# CascadingDropDown fires change event on load

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, asp.net-ajax

We have used the CascadingDropDown for drop downs to populate. When postback happens, the client side change event of the dropdown is fired automatically. This is Firefox 65 specific behavior. In chrome this event is fired only when user manually selects the value from dropdown.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Here is the code.

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   cdlCountries.SelectedValue = "2";
   cdlStates.SelectedValue = "4";
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CS.aspx.cs" Inherits="CS" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=ddlCities.ClientID%>").change(function () {
                alert("");
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
        
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 80px">
                Country:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountries" runat="server" Width="150">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlCountries" TargetControlID="ddlCountries" PromptText="Select Country"
                    PromptValue="" ServicePath="ServiceCS.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCountries" runat="server"
                    Category="CountryId" LoadingText="Loading..." EnableAtLoading="false" />
                <asp:Button ID ="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="btn1_Click" Text="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                State:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStates" runat="server" Width="150">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlStates" TargetControlID="ddlStates" PromptText="Select State"
                    PromptValue="" ServicePath="ServiceCS.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetStates" runat="server"
                    Category="StateId" ParentControlID="ddlCountries" LoadingText="Loading..." EnableAtLoading="false"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                City:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCities" runat="server" Width="150">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlCities" TargetControlID="ddlCities" PromptText="Select City"
                    ServicePath="ServiceCS.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCities" runat="server"
                    Category="CityId" ParentControlID="ddlStates" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Open it in Firefox >> Click on Submit button >> It calls change event of City which should not be called.